# auto colspan to make td center

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dynamic table where I don't know the number of columns. But I want when the number of td is less than usual, first column auto colspan to make `<td>`s center.
For example, I have four columns. I add a `<tr>` where There's are only two columns. I want to set the two 2nd and 3rd position to make it center.

[image]

Here my last `<td>`s become center. I want to achieve this effect. If it is possible with CSS, i'll highly appreciate.

I've the HTML code of the table. But I can't understand how to do it.

HTML:

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td> 
    </tr>    
    <tr >
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
```

Comment: You should provide some code you've use to draw a table.

Comment: `flex` will do this easily using CSS only. Why do you need a table element?

Comment: How do you determine the "*usual*" number of `<td>` elements? And what are you trying to center, the text in the `<td>`? Something else?

Comment: I can tell you already that it's not possible with CSS, nor does it have anything to do with colspans. Instead, whichever way you're generating your content by, that's what you need to adjust in order to get the desired result. I also suspect that you're using tables for layout purposes here, which you shouldn't do - in this case more than for others, as there's a really simple solution using inline-block elements that will get you exactly what you want.

Comment: @max Zuber, I added code by editing. Thank you

Comment: usual number of <td> is determined by default. Max number of column become the number of <td>. I'm trying to center <td>s inside <tr>. In my example, first become blank become other twos center.

Comment: @TheThirdMan Thank you for your comment. I can use inline-block element instead of table. But I'm using the <table> for tabular data except last <tr>. If I add the last <tr> as inline-block element, I have no idea about <td>width.

Comment: Each row in table should have same columns count. Then you can join some cells in row by `colspan` attribute. Do you want to add some cells in the last row on left and right?